# How to speed up the following Linq Query for Stock

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am write Programming in **ASP.NET MVC** with **SQL Database**. I want to get transfer list from database with between Date Range. Also the foreign key relationship with tables like product,Brand,sub-brand. 
Here i wrote the code for getting list but it take time to load.The Database have 3000 records per month.  how to optimize the code?

```
 var stockTransferDetails = db.StockTransferDetails.Where(s => s.BusinessUnitId == BusinessUnitId &&  (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(from) ? s.StockTransfer.TransferDate >= FromDate : true) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(to) ? s.StockTransfer.TransferDate <= ToDate : true)).ToList();
            var stocksummary = from STD in stockTransferDetails.GroupBy(f => f.ProductId).ToList()
                               select new
                               {
                                   BrandName = STD.FirstOrDefault().Product.Brand.BrandName + STD.Where(m => !m.Product.SubBrand.BrandName.Equals("DEF")).Select(s => " - " + s.Product.SubBrand.BrandName).FirstOrDefault(),
                                   ProductName = STD.FirstOrDefault().Product.ProductName,
                                   Packsize = STD.FirstOrDefault().Product.Packsize + " " + STD.FirstOrDefault().Product.UOM.PickListValue,
                                   // TotalQty = (double?)STD.Sum(s => s.ReceievedQty)
                                   Cost = STD.FirstOrDefault().Product.Cost,
                                   TotalCost = (STD.Sum(s => s.ReceievedQty) * STD.FirstOrDefault().Product.Cost)
                               };
            OutletSTIn.Value = stocksummary.ToList();
```

Comment: This is not performance-related but will make your code shorter `(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(from) ? s.StockTransfer.TransferDate >= FromDate : true` can be just `string.IsNullOrEmpty(from) || s.StockTransfer.TransferDate >= FromDate`, similarly `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(to) ? s.StockTransfer.TransferDate <= ToDate : true` can be just `string.IsNullOrEmpty(to) || s.StockTransfer.TransferDate <= ToDate`. Also try debugging to see if the time is taken mostly by the server query (after calling `ToList` on the first line) or by the local query.

Comment: The local query can be improved by caching the value of `STD.FirstOrDefault()` - you call that multiple times which is not very efficient, of course that is just a tiny improvement.

Comment: First why you call ToList() on stockTransferDetails, think of a way to avoid this. Also this shows 3000 records, I'm pretty sure that the user doesn't see a page with 3k records. So add in your query Skip, Take to take only visible records.

Comment: This query for generate RDLC Report. So i want to get all records. @mybirthname

Comment: Okay try to remove ToList() on your first line, also if this is some reporting do it in the background and when is ready sent it to email or whatever you want.